# Indentation error while running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm a newbee to ansible. While running this playbook, getting below error. Although I searched for the solution over the web I was unable to get any help specific to my problem. The problem seems to be with "notify:" syntax but not sure what exactly. Please can anyone help me in finding where is the mistake.

**Ansible playbook -**

```
    ---
 - hosts: droplets
   remote_user: root

   tasks:
   - name: Check if service httpd running
     service: name=httpd state=running
     notify:
     - start apache service

   handlers:
   - name: start apache
     service: name=httpd state=started
...
```

**Output:**

```
   root@zarvis:/home/luckee/ansible# ansible-playbook servicechk.yml -f 2
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/luckee/ansible/servicechk.yml': line 10, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

       - start apache service

^ here
```

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1):

1.) First line. There should be no whitespace characters before three dashes `---` which is called also [Document Boundary Marker](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#document%20boundary%20marker/):

> A line beginning with “---” may be used to explicitly denote the beginning of a new YAML document.

2.)

```
notify:
- start apache service
```

replace with

```
notify:
- start apache
```

since you declaring `start apache` handler.

Comment: After fixing `---` issue I have no syntax errors with latest Ansible `2.0.2.0`

Comment: Even I'm on the same version. Not sure what's wrong. Any other answers please !

Answer (score 0):

### Correct syntax would be:

- hosts: host1
  remote_user: vagrant

  tasks:

  - name: Check if service httpd running
    service: name=httpd state=started
    notify:

    - start_apache

  handlers:

  - name: start apache
    service: name=httpd state=started
    ...